# How to run automated tests with pytest for a package with classes?

Tags: python, class, package, pytest

I am new to using pytest, and running automated tests in general, and I want to know best practice for running automated tests in a python package that contains classes. I have a package, `p`, that contains classes `A`, `B`, and `C`. I have one file, `test_p` which contains four test functions. In order to test these functions, I need to import `A`, `B`, and `C`. The way I'm doing this currently is by having an `__init__.py` file in my `p` repository, which contains the following lines:

```
from p.A import A
from p.B import B
from p.C import C
```

Then, within the directory containing the `p` directory, I launch python and run the commands:

```
from p import *
import pytest
```

then, I navigate inside `p`, and within python run:

```
pytest.main([`test_p`])
```

This procedure for testing my package does not seem optimal to me, and I'm sure there's a better way to do it. Ideally, I would like to be able to just run a script in the OS terminal and/or within the python terminal that runs `test_p`, and have this script exist inside the `p` directory. The issue is that I can't import `A`, `B`, and `C` from within `p` itself. Is there a way to run a script that would run `test_p` (or just run `test_p` directly) without having to navigate between directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution: add the line 
`from p import *` to the `test_p` file, and in `p`'s parent directory, run the following two lines of code in python:

```
import pytest
pytest.main(['p/test_p'])
```